# Logic Error Help: LCG only returns even values

Tags: java, random

I am making two random walk programs one using the Java API Math.random() (which is working fine) and the other using an LCG but the LCG with a range of 8 is only returning even numbers (2, 4, 6, and 8).

I've never tried making my own LCG before and my values of a and c came from a Wikipedia article, if those are the problem and someone has a good way to come up with good values for a and c that would be great. For a seed I am using `System.nanoTime()`.

I also tried other values for a and c both found from Wikipedia and just typing in random numbers but those didn't work either with most only returning 2 and 6 or 4 and 8.

```
public static int getLCGRandom(int randomRange) {
        //For my uses randomRange is always 8

        long a = 6364136223846793005L;
        long c = 1442695040888963407L;

        int number = (int) Math.abs(((System.nanoTime() * a + c) % randomRange)) + 1;

        return  number; 
    }
```

Again, I expect it to be able to output any number 1-8 but it only outputs even numbers.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Returns both even and odd numbers: https://onlinegdb.com/B1r0QS_wH

Comment: This will be platform dependent.  It depends on the resolution that `System.nanoTime()` gives you.  The spec doesn't guarantee that this will be any better than milliseconds, so you're lucky that you don't just get the same value on each call.

Comment: As @DawoodibnKareem said, the source of the problem is using `System.nanoTime()`. If you look at the output of the program in my link, you'll notice that even and odd numbers come in chunks: when something (I'm not sure what) changes with nanoTime, you switch between odd and even numbers.

Comment: And also, unless it's just a minimized example. your implementation of LCG is not correct. LCG generates a *sequence* of numbers (seed used for generating the first one, and the next one depending on the previous one), not one number.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I posted an answer explaining what I ended up doing, it probably isn't the best way of doing it so feedback is appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your comments, I managed to make it use a sequence and found working values of a and c for my system, only using System.nanoTime() to get an INITIAL seed and then using the outputs of the function for future seeds.

```java
    public static int getLCGRandom(int randomRange) {
        long a = 5;
        long c = 2;
        int number = (int) Math.abs(((SeedList.oldSeed * a + c) % randomRange)) + 1;
        SeedList.oldSeed = number;
        return number; 
    }

    static class SeedList {
        static long oldSeed = System.nanoTime();
    }
```

So this doesn't actually work the way i intended because it uses a sequence based solely on the previous output it only repeats the same small loop (with range of 8) which ends up causing my "random walk" to go in a circle and walk with a very clear pattern.